# How to take two sql queries and combine them into a single query

Tags: ms-access, jet

I am making progress on a custom script for my program:

```
// You might want to use a date range and specify the first Sunday and use that variable.
// Or, you may want to have a user request variable where they key in the starting Sunday #YYYY MM DD#

// Let us work out the current week number
$iStartWeekNumber = $Today#CUSTOMDATE[%W] + 1
TEXT "Current week number (1 to 52): $iStartWeekNumber"
EOL

// Let us work out the current year
$iThisYear = $Today#CUSTOMDATE[%Y]
TEXT "Current year: $iThisYear"
EOL

// Now we can do a manual for loop from iStartWeekNumber to the end of the year
TEXT "TODO: Work out how to show the date nicely formatted"
EOL
$datWeek = $Today
LOOP AS $iWeekNumber FROM $iStartWeekNumber TO 52
    $datWeek = $datWeek + 7
    TEXT "Week: $iWeekNumber"
    EOL
    TEXT "Date: {$datWeek#SHORTDATE}"
    EOL

    // Iterate all available speakers
    LOOP FROM "Congregation Speakers" NODATERANGE WHERE "Congregation" IS "$LocalCong" AND "notavail" IS "0"  SORTBY "Speaker"

        // Requirement 1
        // 1. He is not in program for a talk in our home or another congregation for that same WEEKEND (either saturday or sunday)

        // Store the current speaker into a variable
        VARIABLE_FIELD "Speaker" "$strCurrentSpeaker"

        LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Home Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('ww',[Last Given],2)=$iWeekNumber)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Last Given])=$iThisYear)) AND [Speaker] = '$strCurrentSpeaker' AND [Congregation]='$LocalCong'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumHomeTalks"
        END_LOOP

        LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Away Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('ww',[Talk Date],2)=$iWeekNumber)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Talk Date])=$iThisYear)) AND [Brother] = '$strCurrentSpeaker'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumAwayTalks"
        END_LOOP

        IF "$iNumHomeTalks" IS "0" AND "$iNumAwayTalks" IS "0"
            // Requirement 2
            // 2. He should not give a talk more than once in a MONTH (so he is unavailable if he will be giving a talk during the month)
            $iMonth = date_part($datWeek,"M")
            LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Home Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('m',[Last Given])=$iMonth)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Last Given])=$iThisYear)) AND [Speaker] = '$strCurrentSpeaker' AND [Congregation]='$LocalCong'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumHomeTalksForMonth"
            END_LOOP
            LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Away Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('m',[Talk Date])=$iMonth)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Talk Date])=$iThisYear)) AND [Brother] = '$strCurrentSpeaker'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumAwayTalksForMonth"
            END_LOOP
            $iTotalTalksForMonth = $iNumHomeTalksForMonth + $iNumAwayTalksForMonth
            IF "$iTotalTalksForMonth" IS "0"
                // Requirement 3
                // 3. That same weekend either one or more than x speakers are not out for a talk or unavailable

                // TO DO
                TEXT "$strCurrentSpeaker"
                EOL
            END_IF
        END_IF
    END_LOOP

    BLANK *1
END_LOOP
```

I want to specifically bring your attention to two sets of **SQL queries**:

Set 1:

```
LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Home Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('ww',[Last Given],2)=$iWeekNumber)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Last Given])=$iThisYear)) AND [Speaker] = '$strCurrentSpeaker' AND [Congregation]='$LocalCong'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumHomeTalks"
END_LOOP
LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Away Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('ww',[Talk Date],2)=$iWeekNumber)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Talk Date])=$iThisYear)) AND [Brother] = '$strCurrentSpeaker'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumAwayTalks"
END_LOOP
```

And set 2:

```
LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Home Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('m',[Last Given])=$iMonth)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Last Given])=$iThisYear)) AND [Speaker] = '$strCurrentSpeaker' AND [Congregation]='$LocalCong'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumHomeTalksForMonth"
END_LOOP
LOOP SQL "SELECT * FROM [Away Talks] WHERE ((DatePart('m',[Talk Date])=$iMonth)) AND ((DatePart('yyyy',[Talk Date])=$iThisYear)) AND [Brother] = '$strCurrentSpeaker'" ROW_COUNT "$iNumAwayTalksForMonth"
END_LOOP
```

The above is my own scripting language. But under the hood it takes the raw SQL queries and runs it on a Microsoft Access Database using Jet.

They work fine. But I am wondering if the two sets of queries can be combined into one? As you can see, all I am trying to establish is the number of records found. So if I could combine the queries of the `[Home Talks]` and `[Away Talks]` I would end up with only 2 queries to execute instead of four.

It looks to me that I need to use `UNION` but one of the fields is different in each table:

- `Last Given`
- `Talk Date`

So I can't just stitch the keyword `UNION` in between the two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` by aliasing the field names:

```
SELECT [Last Given] AS MyFieldName FROM [Home Talks]
UNION
SELECT [Talk Date] AS MyFieldName FROM [Away Talks]
```

You just have to list individual fields instead of `*` and make sure any output fields match type (or convert to string as part of your query) and name (alias).

Edit: This is an additional option if the two fields are completely unrelated (as opposed to the same or similar information with different field names):

```
SELECT [Last Given], NULL AS [Talk Date] FROM [Home Talks]
UNION
SELECT NULL AS [Last Given], [Talk Date] FROM [Away Talks]
```

Comment: So with the criteria for the two `SELECT` statements, do they then use the aliased field name or original?

Comment: Original names in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` sections as long as you are not using table aliases or sub-queries.

Comment: I added one more option, for cases where the fields in the two tables do not match in context instead of just in name. The same principle can also be used for fields completely missing from one or more of the `UNION`ed tables/queries.